# What are some ways to protect emails on websites from spambots?

Tags: email, spam

I'm creating a public internet facing website which contains the email address of their salespeople.

What  kind of programming options do I have to generate the "mailto" and display the email from that address but limit the spambots from picking up the address?

Answer (score 10):

[Recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/) has an excellent capture based [email protection](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#mailhide).  You can see it implemented at the bottom of any page in my [website](http://tech.dolhub.com) using the Site Feedback link.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the ne version of reCAPTCHA this feature does not exist anymore.

Comment: @lorenzli: Yes it does, I just changed my site email a couple of weeks ago using it. Now at tech.dolhub.com.

Comment: @LawrenceDol https://google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/ gives a 404 error, subdirectories such as /admin/ are redirected to the new site without the mailhide feature.

Comment: @Lorenzli I found the mailhide page with a simple search. Added the link to my answer.

Comment: As of 2022 - Mailhide, the service provided by Google that relies on reCAPTCHA - no longer exists and hasn't for some time. The only Mailhide services is a third-party service, and I'm personally skeptical about since the copyright footer on their website hasn't been updated in 2018. A small thing, maybe, but if they can't get such a small thing right, I'm skeptical they can do such a complex thing as email obfuscation on the modern web.

Answer (score 7):

I know that Facebook does it by displaying an image instead of text. Sure, they could use OCR on the image, but why bother for just one email address?

If you really didn't want spam bots to get an email address, **the best way is to never show it to anyone**. Show a link to "Contact this person" which brings up a form. On the server side, send the contents of that form to the recipient, with a reply-to of the sender's email address. Include a little blurb at the bottom of their message that "if this email is spam, please 'click here' to block this user", which will then block the IP of the sender. I've used this method on a number of occasions and have never had a single complaint.

Comment: What happens if the sender mistypes their email address?

Comment: too bad, i guess. If your users have accounts, you could prefill the sender's name and email address.

Comment: I'm less likely to fill out a form than I'm to write an e-mail.

Comment: The method you mentioned in the second paragraph is great but sometimes those emails are filtered and sent to the spam folder automatically. In those cases, there is a risk that the recipient never see the message.

Answer (score 4):

You can obfuscate it but IMHO whatever you do, one day spammers will get your email address. The future is in spam filters, not trying to keep email addresses secret.

Comment: Yet the harder you work to obfuscate it initially, cutting out the problem at the root, the less hard you will have to work at cutting out spam for the lifetime of your website.

Answer (score 3):

What I have done in the past is use javascript to build the mailto: link. This is nice for the users because they can just click on the link and I don't know of any spambots that take the time to execute javascript yet.

I think I got the idea from [Jakob Nielsen's useit.com](http://www.useit.com) website.

In the page header I have this piece of javascript:

```
<script name="mailto" language="JavaScript">
    //<![CDATA[

    function load()
    {
        c1 = "bcl"
        c2 = "brian"
        c3 = "lane"
        c4 = "com"
        // Fill in the addresses
        document.getElementById("contact1").innerHTML = "<a href=" + "mail" + "to:" + c1 + "@" + c2 + c3 + "." + c4 + ">" + c1 + "@" + c2 + c3 + "." + c4 + "</a>";
    }
    //]]>

</script>
```

Tell it to load it when the page loads:

```
<body onload="load()">
```

And then in the body of the page I put a link to a spamtrap:

```
<span id="contact1"><a href="mailto:spam@brianlane.com">spam@brianlane.com</a></span>
```

Comment: That may work against the simple bots, but a spider that understands enough Javascript (or parses the generated source code) can easily collect the e-mail addresses.

Comment: for XHTML compliance so you can use < and &

Comment: Do you think this method has an effect on indexing of the website. Is it maybe important that Google should index the email address, or is that not important.

Comment: @SaifBechan If you're trying to avoid spam, then you absolutely do not want Google or any other search engines indexing your email address.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a static HTML page, but a ASP.NET, JSP, Coldfusion, or PHP page then you could have a drop down box with a list of all your sales people, a text box for comments,  and a "Contact Us" (ie, Submit button).  When the button is clicked, it will call a server-side code which creates the email and sends it to your local mail server for delivery.  The outside world will never know the email address of your sales people, nor the email format (ie, firstname.lastname@yourcompany.com) of your company.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at PrivateDaddy - I think it does exactly what you're looking for: fully automatic, unobtrusive email cloaking that even works with browsers where JavaScript support is disabled.  You can get it [here](http://www.privatedaddy.com/) (free of course)

Comment: I work on a community web site with many (10K+) email addrs in user generated content - was going to implement a server side parsing code + image generation to do the trick - ended up implementing it with Privatedaddy and left the data intact.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but not only does PrivateDaddy obfuscation appear to leave the text unobfuscated (which may be a benefit for some), but the [example](https://www.privatedaddy.com/example) it gives does not seem to be obfuscating anything at all. I followed its advice and checked the page's source, and it showed the full email address both in `mailto:` and text form.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, well, more of a theory.
Problem is, the bots parse the page. they can get the text. even if it's being put
into the page in some sophisticated way through Javascript.

So, just you *CSS3 pseudo element*! it won't be a link, but your email will be visible, and will never be an actual text. something like this:

```
.email::after{ content:'myemail@gmail.com'; }
```

Again, it's a theory, I've no idea how far these evil people can go to get it, but I think this be pretty safe.

---

### Update (JULY 19')

I now in the opinion this isn't a problem since email servers have become good at filtering spam and there's no reason to make any elaborate tricks to "protect" email text on webpages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like email [obfuscation](http://alicorna.com/obfuscator.html)

Comment: I can be wrong, but I believe that nowadays it is inefficient. I doubt spammer's crawlers are unable to decode entities, since the trick is well known now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem.  If you post an e-mail such that it can be parsed by a web browser so that it's clickable, then it can be parsed by a spambot.  If it's not clickable (e.g. if it's an image), it's more difficult for users.  On one side is perfect, seamless experience for users and on the other side is perfect spam-blocking.  A simple CSS or javascript to take in an email address as separate tokens is usually better than nothing, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could only show a part of the e-mail address "us...@mail.com" as a link that redirects to a captcha, then display the full e-mail address like Google Groups does.

Comment: That's the reCaptcha solution above.

Answer (score 0):

We used to do classic ASP string cat for email addresses, the grand idea being that spambots read source, but don't parse server-side code. I have NO idea if that actually works.

Comment: ? If you look at the source and see the plain e-mail, it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

Would something that I wrote work for you?

http://kevin-le.appspot.com/viewSource/sourceShare/asmRevealer.js

...and you could see the demo here:

http://kevin-le.appspot.com/extra/contact

It works with mailto, so it's convenient for users, but spambots won't be able to pick up which is your requirements.  It'll be obvious once you spend 1 minute looking at the demo.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too and i came up with a quick but effective method to help my website out.
Basically bots just read the content of the web page but in 99.999% they do not trigger events, it would require a great amount of dedication and work, things hacker don't usually do in favor of bigger numbers and quicker effects.
So i came up with this function:

```
function emptyMail() {
    let mail = document.querySelector('#your_mail');
    let mailValue = mail.href;

    mail.href = "";

    mail.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      mail.href= mailValue;
    })
}
```

This worked for me i hope it can help you too.

Answer (score -2):

I see the mailto: protocol almost dead anyway... It is convenient, but too easy to parse and gather.

Plus it has its downsides: if you are on a Web cafe, it won't work because it will call whatever default e-mail client it has (if it has any!) and it is not set up on your account. Same if you use exclusively online e-mail managers...

A possible workaround is to decorate e-mails, relying on users to type or correct them: foo (at) example.com or foo-NOSPAM@REMOVE-THIS-example.com are common schemes (hoping spammers doesn't try to decipher these common schemes!), graphical e-mail addresses are another way.

Or, as pointed out, if you can, the best option is to have a contact form, with [some reasonable form of protection against robots](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html), that would be usable from everywhere. Although people might be defiant on forms asking for e-mails (for response!), so a disclaimer might be useful too... :-)

Comment: If you see a mailto: link, most browsers allow you to copy the link location or the e-mail address.  Some browsers may also be configured to support webmail, even if you need a plugin or extension.

Comment: mailto isn't dead! email is the core of internet, how could people talk to each other without it? it's so basic. you click a link, then write whatever to that person. how can it be easier?