# Why is reCAPTCHA allowing spam?

Tags: recaptcha, gravityforms

I work as a webdesigner in a firm and we use CAPTCHA on sites we make. Lately some of our customers have complained about getting spam emails, even with reCAPTCHA activated. I see the first spam email came the 1. of February, and its been coming more and more for every day since. There are no messages of error, and they havent had spam before. This is happening on different sites, and none have had a problem before. Site and Secret key is valid on both. We use Gravity Forms for the forms, and Gravity Forms have integrated CAPTCHA if you have it. Is there something I am missing? There is no messages of error on the sites. Can it be that the robots can now get passed it? :P

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the email adress is already indexed in some spam mailing list or that you have on your website anchor links like this:

```
<a href="mailto:someemail@adress.com">email me</a>
```

In the first case you can ask for anti-spam solutions from your host provider, in the second case you can checkout this post:

[How to stop spammers from getting the email address from a mailto link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769894/how-to-stop-spammers-from-getting-the-email-address-from-a-mailto-link)

Comment: Thank you for this, but this isnt where the spam comes. In gravity forms, you can access all the input from the website, in addition to recieving them to the e-mail. And since I can see the spam from the Gravity Forms in the WP dashboard, it tells me the spam came through the form it self :) Google reCAPTCHA has always stopped it but in february suddendly spam came through... :/